# youtube-dl no longer has audio in partial files

Tags: youtube-dl

I use `youtube-dl` to download videos, and while downloading I start watching with `vlc`.

`youtube-dl` used to download video+audio simultaneously so you could play the partial file. But recently a change to `youtube-dl` causes it to download first video, then audio, which is then eventually merged into a single file. So you would have to wait for the download to complete before starting to watch.

Is there a way I can activate the old behaviour?

Comment: Guess: That behaviour only applies to "dashboard" formats with separate video and audio. Try `youtube-dl -F` to see available formats for a specific video, and `youtube-dl -f formatname` to choose a format that isn't split in audio and video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-f best` to download video and audio in a single file. But keep in mind that the resolution is limited to 1280x720.